# MongoDB: Filter documents by multiple aspects sharing same value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this

```
{
    "productId" : ObjectId("someId-1"),
    "value" : "Nike",
    "key" : "Brand",
},

{
    "productId" : ObjectId("someId-1"),
    "value" : "Blue",
    "key" : "Color",
},

{
    "productId" : ObjectId("someId-2"),
    "value" : "Nike",
    "key" : "Brand",
},

{
    "productId" : ObjectId("someId-2"),
    "value" : "Red",
    "key" : "Color",
},
```

and I want to make a query to get all product Ids that share these aspects

```
[
  {
    key: "Brand",
    value: "Nike",
  },
  {
    key: "Color",
    value: "Blue",
  },
]
```

And this should return `productId = someId-1`

Note that I want to make use of indexes created on all three fields(productId, key, value)

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have you tried using $or specifying the conditions?

Comment: Yes, I tried $or alongside with the $group on productId as the key, but this make use of the index on key and value part not the productId part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached some point that may be the best way to handle this issue

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { key: 'Model', value: 'GV Special' },
                {
                    key: 'Brand',
                    value: 'Puma'
                },
                {
                    key: 'Color',
                    value: 'Multicolor'
                }]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$productId",
            products: { $push: "$productId" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            products: { $size: 3 }
        }
    }
])
```

But this the last match `$size` should be the number of aspects you want to match from the `$or` operator.

So, if we wanted only 2 conditions from `$or` to be applied we will change the `$size` to be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$lookup`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "key": 'Brand', 'value':'Nike' }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "localField": "productId",
    "foreignField": "productId",
    "as": "ids"
  }}
])
```

It will do a simple join in the same collection.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: The lookup part is not the problem I'm facing here. I want to search on the collection with some aspects combined form (key, value). but sharing the same productId

Comment: Can you explain bit more?

Comment: I have a collection that has keys [key, value, productId].
I want to make a query that accepts an array like this
[
  {
    key: "Brand",
    value: "Nike",
  },
  {
    key: "Color",
    value: "Blue",
  },
] 
All the array conditions are applied but within the **same product**.

So we will have all products that have brand is Nike and color is blue

Comment: That is really not possible with values shared across multiple documents. If you use $or, you will end up with unwanted items.

Comment: Exactly, I want to get rid of these unwanted items.

Comment: you need to use lookup or two queries